# Handle ResourceNotFoundException, message not good

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I use spring boot and I start to manage error.

I create an exception handling to treat resources that are not found.

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class RestResponseEntityExceptionHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {

    @ExceptionHandler(ResourceNotFoundException.class)
    private ResponseEntity<Void> handleResourceNotFoundException(ResourceNotFoundException e) {
        return ResponseEntity.notFound().build();
    }
}
```

In my Controller I do

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/members/{memberId}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity getMemberById(@PathVariable("memberId") Long memberId) throws ResourceNotFoundException {
    MemberDto memberDto = memberService.getMemberById(memberId);
    return new ResponseEntity(memberDto, HttpStatus.OK);
}

@Override
public MemberDto getMemberById(Long memberId) throws ResourceNotFoundException {
    Member member = memberRepository.findOne(memberId);

    if (member == null) {
        throw new ResourceNotFoundException("Member not found");
    }

    return convertToMemberDto(member);
}
```

I have only a few members, so if I call

localhost:/members/999

I see in the response headers chrome

```
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: 0
X-Frame-Options: DENY
Content-Length: 0
Date: Tue, 19 Jul 2016 01:04:25 GMT
```

Why I don't get the message: *Member not found?*
Is this a good way to manage errors with spring boot?
How to manage different types of errors in the controller?

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to change your exception handler to return a body with the error message you want to return, i.e.:

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class RestResponseEntityExceptionHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {

    @ExceptionHandler(ResourceNotFoundException.class)
    private ResponseEntity<Void> handleResourceNotFoundException(ResourceNotFoundException e) {
          // log exception
          return ResponseEntity
            .status(HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN)
            .body("Member not found");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

https://www.baeldung.com/spring-response-status-exception

Starting from the 2.3 version, Spring Boot doesn't include an error message on the default error page. The reason is to reduce the risk of leaking information to a client

To change the default behavior, we can use a server.error.include-message property.

Let's set it to always and see what happens:

$ curl -i -s -X GET http://localhost:8081/actor/8
HTTP/1.1 404
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Date: Sat, 26 Dec 2020 19:39:11 GMT

{
"timestamp": "2020-12-26T19:39:11.426+00:00",
"status": 404,
"error": "Not Found",
"message": "Actor Not Found",
"path": "/actor/8"
}

As we can see, this time, the response contains an “Actor Not Found” error message.